# Text analysis using Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

If I have a training set of data (say 1/2 page per row) and I have a boolean flag AboutFishYesNo for each row is it possible to develop a model using Microsoft Azure Machine Learning to guess the AboutFishYesNo flag?

Are there any pre-built templates or how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a binary classification problem. There's no pre-built templates to do this task. But you can create a feature set using the textual data and build a classifier easily.